# How do i scrape a pop up element without using selenium

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrap this url [text](https://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/index.php/Chome/profil/90FE8890-2EF5-E011-80B0-0D6197D81E63)
with Beautiful soup but there is a pop up element that requires clicking to open a popup window. How can i achieve that without using selenium.

```
import random
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_agents = [
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
]

user_agent = random.choice(user_agents)
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}

href = 'https://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/index.php/Chome/profil/90FE8890-2EF5-E011-80B0-0D6197D81E63'
page = requests.get(href, headers=headers)
if page.status_code == 200:
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    location_element = page_soup.find('h4', class_='page-header')
    location_text = location_element.get_text(strip=True)
    location_id = location_text.strip('()')
    location_road = location_element.find('i', class_='glyphicon glyphicon-road').next_sibling.strip()

    school_element = page_soup.find('ul', class_='list-group list-group')
    school_text = school_element.text.strip().split('\n')
    accreditation = school_text[1].split(':')[-1].strip()
    principal = school_text[2].split(':')[-1].strip()
    operator = school_text[3].split(':')[-1].strip()


    leaf_element = page_soup.find('div', class_='leaflet-marker-pane')
    leaf_text = leaf_ele.text.strip()
    print(leaf_text)
```

if you check the url, it's a google leaflet icon, you click to open a pop up window. Is there another approach that i could use. Note: I have over 10 000 such urls and i want to scrape in the fastest way possible.

if i use selenium everything works fine. But i would prefer to use Beautiful soup and request. the approach is much quicker.

```
href = 'https://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/index.php/Chome/profil/90FE8890-2EF5-E011-80B0-0D6197D81E63'
page = requests.get(href, headers=headers)
if page.status_code == 200:
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    location_element = page_soup.find('h4', class_='page-header')
    location_text = location_element.get_text(strip=True)
    location_id = location_text.strip('()')
    location_road = location_element.find('i', class_='glyphicon glyphicon-road').next_sibling.strip()

    school_element = page_soup.find('ul', class_='list-group list-group')
    school_text = school_element.text.strip().split('\n')
    accreditation = school_text[1].split(':')[-1].strip()
    principal = school_text[2].split(':')[-1].strip()
    operator = school_text[3].split(':')[-1].strip()


    leaf_ele = page_soup.find('div', class_='leaflet-marker-pane')
    leaf_text = leaf_ele.text.strip()
    print(leaf_text)
```

i cant scrape the leaf element text.

Answer (score 1):

The data in the leaflet is stored in javascript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can try to use `re` module to parse the data:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# important! put /chome/ in lowercase!
url = "https://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/index.php/chome/profil/90FE8890-2EF5-E011-80B0-0D6197D81E63"


def get_leaflet(html_text, url):
    html_from_js = "\n".join(re.findall(r"^\s*'(<.*?>)'[+;]", html_text, flags=re.M))
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html_from_js, "html.parser")
    # find the right `<ul>`
    leaflet = soup2.select_one(f'ul:has(a[href="{url}"])')
    return leaflet


html_text = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
# ...get other data from soup

# get leaflet from the `html_text`:
print(get_leaflet(html_text, url))
```

Prints:

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-unbordered">
<li class="list-group-item text-info"><a href="https://sekolah.data.kemdikbud.go.id/index.php/chome/profil/90FE8890-2EF5-E011-80B0-0D6197D81E63" target="_blank">10108211</a></li>
<li class="list-group-item text-muted">SDN KEUEB</li>
<li class="list-group-item text-muted"><b>Alamat</b> : Jln.Peurin</li>
<li class="list-group-item text-muted"><a href="https://maps.google.co.id/maps?expflags=enable_star_based_justifications:true&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;f=d&amp;daddr=4.305800000000,95.984200000000" target="_blank">Direction</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It worked, one more thing. Now I want to get specific texts inside the leaflet I.e 

school_id = 10108211
school_name = SDN KEUEB
Address = Jln.Peurin
google_maps = https://maps.google.co.id/maps?expflags=enable_star_based_justifications:true&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;f=d&amp;daddr=4.305800000000,95.984200000000

Comment: @Tosh_gitonga `leaflet` is beautifulsoup object, so I think you can do `id_, name, address, *_ = leaflet.select('li')`